# ¿Como hago para mostrar un Toast o tostada cada ves que mi lista aumenta o disminuye?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una lista que aumenta constantemente cada cierto tiempo, quiero que cuando mi lista aumenta o disminuya  me muestre un `Toast`.

Estuve intentando pero no puedo.

Esto es mi código:

```
frutasList = new ArrayList<Datos>();

List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < frutasList.size(); i++) {
            lables.add(frutasList.get(i).getName() + " fecha" + frutasList.get(i).getFecha());
            dato.add(frutasList.get(i).getName() + "  fecha y hora:" + frutasList.get(i).getFecha());
            //lables.add(frutasList.get(i).getFecha());

        }
        if(this.frutasList.size()!=frutasList.size()){    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cambio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            }
        names = this.dato;

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

```
 codigo completo   _______________________________
```

//  si presiono el item adname  se actualizan los datos cada un segundo  en base al los datos del servidor 
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_name:
                this.addName(0);  // si pulso el item adname  se actualizan los datos
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

```
private void addName(int position) {
```

StartTimer();  // empiezan a actualizarse constanetemente los datos
 }

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable handlerTask;

void StartTimer(){
    handler = new Handler();
    handlerTask = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(handlerTask, 1000);  // se actualizan los datos cada un segundo
           updateData();  //  se llama al metodo actualizar
        }
    };
    handlerTask.run();
}

 //   metodo  actualizar
```

private void updateData() {

`// Clear dato..
 dato.clear();
 // Refresh your listview..
    populateSpinner();
    frutasList = new ArrayList<Datos>();
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < frutasList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(frutasList.get(i).getName() + " fecha" + frutasList.get(i).getFecha());
        dato.add(frutasList.get(i).getName() + "  fecha y hora:" + frutasList.get(i).getFecha());
        //lables.add(frutasList.get(i).getFecha());

    }
      /*         quiero  saber el aumento o disminucion de la lista   **************************************************/
    if(this.frutasList.size()!=frutasList.size()){    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cambio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            }
    names = this.dato;

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    new Getfrutas().execute();

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

}`

}

Comment: *Tengo una lista que aumenta constantemente cada cierto tiempo...* ¿Y cuál es el **evento** que provoca que tu lista aumente? Tienes que *escuchar*  ese evento y hacer la comparación cuando el mismo ocurra.

Comment: la lista se actualiza constantemente segun una base de datos externa,  si en la base de datos aumento datos, la lista aumenta tambien, pero no se como ponerle el Toast

Comment: Pon tu asynctask para ver el codigo, es ahi en el onpostexecute donde deberias mostrar el toast

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la mejor opcion es declarar 2 metodos:

```
agregar(){
}

remover(){
}
```

En cada metodo haces la operacion correspondiente de la lista que estas modificando y al finalizar el metodo llamas a :

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La lista ha cambiado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Lo importante es que no llames a los metodos add del array list directamente.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo este ejemplo en Kotlin, talvez puedas pasarlo a Java o darte una idea.

```
private lateinit var adapter: MyAdapter
private val myFruitList:  MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
```

Creas los métodos en el adaptador

```
fun agregar(fruta:String) {
   myFruitList.add(fruta)
   notifyItemInserted(myFruitList.size - 1)
   //Toast correspondiente 
}

//Puedes pasarle alguno de estos parámetros: la cadena que vas a borrar (tiene que ser igual a la que ya está en la lista) o la posición que vas a borrar
fun remover(posición: Int) {
    myFruitList.remove(posición)
    notifyItemRemoved(posición)
    //Toast correspondiente 
}

//Si le pasas la cadena como parámetro
fun remover(fruta: String) {
   val posición = myFruitList.indexOf(fruta)
   if (posición != -1) {
     myFruitList.remove(posición)
     notifyItemRemoved(posición)
     //Toast correspondiente 
   }
}
```

Y después los mandas a llamar cuando los ocupes

```
override fun onCreate() {
    adapter = MyAdapter(myFruitList)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    val myFruits: List<String> = listOf("manzana", "pera", "naranja", "uva",...,"etc")


    for (f in myFruits) {
       adapter.agregar(f)
    }

    adapter.remover("pera" o 1) //dependiendo cuál usaste.
```

De esta manera ahorras muchos recursos ya que notificas al adaptador de los cambios exactos realizados en lugar de notificar toda la data completa, tendrás animaciones de agregado y eliminado (ya que estás se remueven si pones el adaptador al RecyclerView cada que modificas los datos), y además es lo que buscabas.

Comment: Saludos @ChuyPorras, es genial que quieras ayudar, pero en este caso la pregunta especifica la etiqueta JAVA, es mejor dar una respuesta con los requerimientos solicitados para no confundir a OP. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Por lo que veo el array `dato` es el contiene la lista que cargas en el listView, por lo que el tamaño de este es el que tienes que evaluar para saber si la lista ha aumentado de tamaño o no.

Para hacerlo, obtén el tamaño del array antes y después de actualizarlo. Luego compara los dos tamaños en un condicional y de acuerdo al resultado lanzas un `Toast`.

```
// obtienes el tamaño de la lista antes de actualizarla
int sizeAntes = dato.size();

dato.clear();

populateSpinner();
frutasList = new ArrayList<Datos>();
List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < frutasList.size(); i++) {
    lables.add(frutasList.get(i).getName() + " fecha" + frutasList.get(i).getFecha());
    dato.add(frutasList.get(i).getName() + "  fecha y hora:" + frutasList.get(i).getFecha());
}

// obtienes el tamaño de la lista después de actualizarla
int sizeDespues = dato.size(); 

// Evalúas el tamaño de la lista: si el valor de sizeAntes es menor al de sizeDespués 
// la condición se cumple. Lo que quiere decir que el tamaño de la lista es mayor, de lo
// contrario la condición no se cumple, por lo cual el tamaño de la lista es menor.
if (sizeAntes < sizeDespues) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El tamaño de la lista es mayor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El tamaño de la lista es menor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```